# Reference for: simple closed curves generate the fundamental group

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

In a 2-complex $X$, it is "obvious" that the simple closed curves through the $0$-cell $v$ generate the fundamental group $\pi_1(X, v)$. (By a "simple closed curve" I mean a loop which does not self-intersect.)

Do you have a reference for this which I can cite? Hatcher does not prove this, so far as I can see.

Comment: Hint: First, try to prove it if $X$ is a graph.

Comment: I can prove it (perhaps I shouldn't have put "obvious" in quote marks!) - the issue is the reference.

Comment: Why do you need a reference? For something so straightforward you could either just give the proof or leave it to the reader.

Comment: @Mike I am never sure how obvious things are to other people, so I'd rather give a reference than "leave it to the reader" if I can. Giving a proof detracts from the point. Also, its nice to have references to obvious things, and it not being in Hatcher made me wonder where it would be instead.

Comment: I think it is one of those cases when it is easier to give a proof than find a reference.

Comment: This is an immediate corollary of cellular approximation, for instance. Just say that.

Answer (score 4):

Some obvious things are less obvious than others....

Let $X$ be a rank two graph consisting of a disjoint pair of circles plus an arc with one endpoint on each circle. Then no matter what $v \in X$ you pick, $\pi_1(X,v)$ is not generated by simple closed curves through $v$.

Comment: Bum. Is the following correct then: "paths $p$ and $q$ are homeomorphic if and only if there exists a partitioning of $p$ and $q$ into simple curves $p=u_1\ldots u_n$, $q=v_1\ldots v_n$" with each $u_i$, $v_i$ homeomorphic? (Again, obvious. And again, I can prove it (induct on $n$). But I could also prove the statement in my question...)

Comment: I'm not sure how to address your question. What does it mean for two paths to be homeomorphic?

Comment: Sorry, I meant homotopic!

Comment: ...I'm also assuming that if if $f_i$ is the homotopy with $f_i(u_i)=v_i$ then $f(\iota(u_i))=\iota(v_I)$ and $f(\tau(u_i))=\tau(v_I)$...

Comment: Perhaps there might be a different question to pose here, if you can carefully formulate what you want. But I imagine that this kind of thing could only hold in quite restrictive situations, e.g. geodesic paths in graphs.